# Generate List if a Condition is Met

Tags: excel, vba

I want to Copy and Paste or Generate a list if a Function is met.

This is my code, it calculates until K5>=71 but it doesnt paste. And I want it to paste atleast 10 sets of List. Please check whats wrong in my code or please suggest how to improve it.

```
  Sub Generatelist()
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Do While Range("K5") < 71
Calculate
If K5 >= 71 Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:I3").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A92").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)* and you will see your first mistake: `K5` is not `Range("K5")`  instead `K5` is a not declared variable. Also `Range("K5")` needs to be specified in which sheet it is eg `ws.Range("K5")`. • Also don't use `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:I3")` if you already declared a variable for the sheet. Use `ws.Range("A3:I3")` instead.

Comment: ok thanks! I am working on mac so i dont know if theres a difference, from what I know I cant find the Require Variable Declaration.

Comment: This code worked! Thanks to you hihi. God Bless!

Comment: Instead of using copy/paste, couldn't you just `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A92:I92").Value=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:I3").Value`